# Using YAML files in esbuild

Tags: react-i18next, esbuild

My app is using the contents of YAML files (for i18next translations). When developing using `create-react-app` (and CRACO), the YAML files are being read no problem .

However after building my app for deployment using `esbuild`, the app dies with this console error:

```
index.ts:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: globRequire_yaml is not defined
    at index.ts:4:28
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at index.ts:3:44
    at index.ts:4:72
```

The line with the error can be seen below:

```
["de", "en", "es", "fr", "ja", "pt", "zh"].forEach((locale) => {
  const contents = require(`./${locale}.yml`);  // <---- this is where it is failing
  Object.assign(locales, contents);
});
```

Here is my esbuild.js:

```js
// .esBuild.js
const esbuild = require("esbuild");
const { sassPlugin } = require("esbuild-sass-plugin");
const inlineImportPlugin = require("esbuild-plugin-inline-import");
const { yamlPlugin } = require("esbuild-plugin-yaml");

esbuild
  .build({
    entryPoints: ["src/index.js"],
    outfile: "build/input.js",
    bundle: true,
    minify: true,
    sourcemap: true,
    plugins: [inlineImportPlugin(), sassPlugin(), yamlPlugin()],
    loader: {
      ".js": "jsx",
      ".woff": "file",
      ".woff2": "file",
      ".yaml": "file",
    },
  })
  .catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe something in the `loader` config setting?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve by requiring individually, which would make it not require at runtime:

```
const locales = {};

["de", "en", "es", "fr", "ja", "pt", "zh"].forEach((locale) => {
  const contents = require(`./${locale}.yaml`); 
  Object.assign(locales, contents);
});

export default locales;
```

to

```
const de = require(`./de.yaml`);
const en = require(`./en.yaml`);
const es = require(`./es.yaml`);
const fr = require(`./fr.yaml`);
const ja = require(`./ja.yaml`);
const pt = require(`./pt.yaml`);
const zh = require(`./zh.yaml`);

const locales = { de, en, es, fr, ja, pt, zh };

export default locales;
```